# TCPDF - Only Persian language showing - Custom font

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, farsi

The font is for Persian characters but I want English and other chars to be rendered normally using normal fonts not the one I set.
[image]

Code:

```
    $pdf = new \TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
    $lg = Array();
    $lg['a_meta_charset'] = 'UTF-8';
    $lg['a_meta_dir'] = 'rtl';
    $lg['a_meta_language'] = 'fa';
    $lg['w_page'] = 'page';
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($lg);
    $fontname = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont(storage_path('bnazanin.ttf'), 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 96);
    $pdf->SetFont($fontname);
    $pdf->AddPage();


    $htmlpersian = '<span color="#660000">Persian example:</span><br />سلام بالاخره مشکل PDF فارسی به طور کامل حل شد. اینم یک نمونش.<br />مشکل حرف \"ژ\" در بعضی کلمات مانند کلمه ویژه نیز بر طرف شد.<br />نگارش حروف لام و الف پشت سر هم نیز تصحیح شد.<br />با تشکر از  "Asuni Nicola" و محمد علی گل کار برای پشتیبانی زبان فارسی.';
    $pdf->WriteHTML($htmlpersian, true, 0, true, 0);
    $pdf->setRTL(false);
    $pdf->Ln();
    
    $pdf->Output('example.pdf', 'I');
```

Comment: If you want the font to be different for different pieces of the text, wouldn't it be logical that you have to tell the library that? How could this library know what characters are English, or even better, which characters are not available in the font you set? And how would it know what other font to switch to?

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche How do browsers or text processors know? Same here.

Comment: They don't. They use the font you give it.

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche Ok, I think I have to merge this font with a normal font

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using a font which also has English characters